# How to create mysql databse in git lab CI/CD yaml file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new gitlab CI/CD. I have created a simple yaml script to build and test my php application. I am using shared runner option available in gitlab CI.
I have specified the database name "MYSQL_DATABASE" and it doesn't seem to make any effect.

How do I specify that? Is there any other way to create database in YAML file. When I specify create database, build is getting failed stating

```
"/bin/bash: line 78: create: command not found".
```

Comment: can you share the yml file? if you are using docker executor you can use mysql as a service https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/

Comment: The `create database` command you have in your YAML is being executed as a shell command, and not a database command.  Where is your database running? 
 Are you sure you have a database running?  You can [run one as a service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html) if you're running on Kubernetes.  Please share your YAML.

Comment: I am not running  in Kubernetes. I am running in the available shared runner. stages:
      - build   
      - test   
services:
  - name: mysql:5.7.24
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: xxx
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
building:
  stage: build
  image: php:7.2
  script:
  - php some commands
  - php some commands
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 month
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - .env
phpunit:
  stage: test
  image: php:7.2
  script:
    - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --colors --verbose --configuration phpunit.xml

Comment: Any help on this

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to help without knowing more about your configuration. As user JGC already stated, the main error cause seems to be that you are trying to run `create database` as bash command.

If you want to create a MySQL database directly on a Linux command-line, you can use

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -e "CREATE DATABASE database-name
```

However, with GitLab CI you should try to use one of the solutions described at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html

With the Docker executor (e.g. with the SaaS version via gitlab.com) you can just use the following in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: database-name
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_strong_password
```

Comment: what if i want to create mutiple database? i can use service:alias, but in that case how can set the variable??